# Select element only if it is immidiatly followed by another element

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript if I get all li elements with getElementsByTagName("li"); how do I then only select li elements that are directly followed by span? For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>test<span style="color: red;"> A</span>dfg</li>
  <li><span style="color: red;">Test B</span>dfg</li>
</ul>
```

Here I want only to select 2nd li because it is followed by span immediately and not the first one because it opens with text.

Comment: I think you need get element with `document.querySelectorAll('li .class span')`, If you select element 2nd. Give a class in 2nd li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function below collects an li element(how ever way you get the element), and checks if its first child element is a span and returns it

```
function checkElem(elem) {
    // check if the element is an li element
    if (elem.tagName != "LI") {
        // if its not, return false
        console.log("The element passed is not an li element");
        return false;
    } else {
        // get the first child element of the li
        var firstChild = elem.firstChild;

        // check if the first child is a span tag
        if (firstChild.tagName == "SPAN") {
            // return the li element
            return elem;
        } else {
            // else return false
            console.log("List item's first element is not a span");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So u can use like this

```
var liElements = getElementsByTagName("li");

liElements.forEach(li => {
    var myLi = checkElem(li);
    
    if(myLi != false){
        myLi.style.fontSize = "30px";
    }
})
```